# Checking the input fields in html table is empty or not for adding dynamic rows

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hi I am having the html table which contain several columns, by pressing tab to add rows dynamically in the html table.i want to check that first and second input field is empty or not in html table. whether that input fields is empty rows not to get to added in dynamically. my problem is that validation is only working for first rows and not for dynamic rows.

```
   <form id='students' method='post' id="form1" name='form1' action='index.php'>
                <div class="table-responsive" id="nm">
                  <div  align="center">
                    <b><input type="text" name="total_amt" id="total_amt" value="" maxlength="200" height="130px"; width="200px"; style="font-size:60pt;height:110px;width:600px;" align="center"; /></b>
                             </div>

                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th><input class='check_all' type='checkbox' onclick="select_all()"/></th>
                            <th>S. No</th>
                            <th>Country Name</th>
                            <th>Country Number</th>
                            <th>Country Phone code</th>
                            <th>Country code</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td>
                            <td><span id='snum'>1.</span></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" type='text' id='countryname_1' name='countryname[]' autofocus /></td>
                            <td class="td_class"><input class="form-control country_no" type='text' id='country_no_1' name='country_no[]'/></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" disabled type='text' id='phone_code_1' name='phone_code[]'/></td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" disabled type='text' id='country_code_1' name='country_code[]'/> </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <button type="button" class='btn btn-danger delete'>- Delete</button>
                    <button type="button" class='btn btn-success addmore'>+ Add More</button>
                </div>

            </form>


   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".td_class").on('keyup', '#country_no_1', function(e) {   

        var icon1 = $('#countryname_1').val();

             var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
                 if (keyCode == 9 ) {
                    if(icon1 == '' )
                    {

                     alert("Please Select an Item");
                    document.form1.countryname_1.focus();
                    }

                   else{                        
                   $(".addmore").click();
                   }
                } });

        });
     </script>
```

Here am adding the script code below:

```
     <script>
          $(".delete").on('click', function() {
         $('.case:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
        $('.check_all').prop("checked", false); 
      check();
      });
     var i=$('table tr').length;

     $(".addmore").on('click',function(){
     count=$('table tr').length;

         var data="<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='case'/></td><td><span id='snum"+i+"'>"+count+".</span></td>";
        data +="<td><input class='form-control' type='text' id='countryname_"+i+"' name='countryname[]'/></td> <td class='td_class'><input class='form-control country_no' type='text' id='country_no_"+i+"' name='country_no[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control' type='text' disabled id='phone_code_"+i+"' name='phone_code[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control' disabled type='text' id='country_code_"+i+"' name='country_code[]'/></td></tr>";
        $('table').append(data);
    /*test */


      $(".td_class").on('keyup', '#country_no_'+i, function(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
              if (keyCode == 9) { 
                e.preventDefault();                     
                $(".addmore").click();
              } 
        });
        /* test end */
    row = i ;
     $('#countryname_'+i).autocomplete({
     source: function( request, response ) {
      $.ajax({
        url : 'ajax.php',
        dataType: "json",
        method: 'post',
        data: {
           name_startsWith: request.term,
           type: 'country_table',
           row_num : row
        },
         success: function( data ) {
             response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                var code = item.split("|");
                return {
                    label: code[0],
                    value: code[0],
                    data : item
                }
            }));
        }
         });
     },
      autoFocus: true,          
      minLength: 0,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
      var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
      id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
      id = id_arr.split("_");                   
      $('#country_no_'+id[1]).val(names[1]);
      $('#phone_code_'+id[1]).val(names[2]);
      $('#country_code_'+id[1]).val(names[3]);
      }             
      });


    i++;
   });

     function select_all() {
     $('input[class=case]:checkbox').each(function(){ 
      if($('input[class=check_all]:checkbox:checked').length == 0){ 
        $(this).prop("checked", false); 
        } else {
         $(this).prop("checked", true); 
       } 
    });
    }

    function check(){
    obj=$('table tr').find('span');
     $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
    id=value.id;
    $('#'+id).html(key+1);
   });
  }

    $('#countryname_1').autocomplete({
     source: function( request, response ) {
      $.ajax({
         url : 'ajax.php',
         dataType: "json",
         method: 'post',
         data: {
           name_startsWith: request.term,
           type: 'country_table',
           row_num : 1
        },
         success: function( data ) {
             response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                var code = item.split("|");
                return {
                    label: code[0],
                    value: code[0],
                    data : item
                }
            }));
          }
       });
   },
   autoFocus: true,         
   minLength: 0,
   select: function( event, ui ) {
    var names = ui.item.data.split("|");                        
    $('#country_no_1').val(names[1]);
    $('#phone_code_1').val(names[2]);
    $('#country_code_1').val(names[3]);
  }             
 });

   $('#country_code_1').autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
       $.ajax({
         url : 'ajax.php',
         dataType: "json",
         method: 'post',
         data: {
            name_startsWith: request.term,
            type: 'country_code',
            row_num : 1
         },
          success: function( data ) {
              response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                 var code = item.split("|");
                 return {
                    label: code[3],
                    value: code[3],
                    data : item
                }
            }));
           }
      });
  },
   autoFocus: true,         
   minLength: 0,
   select: function( event, ui ) {
    var names = ui.item.data.split("|");                    
    $('#country_no_1').val(names[1]);
    $('#phone_code_1').val(names[2]);
    $('#countryname_1').val(names[0]);
},
open: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
},
close: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
}               
 });

       </script>
```

Help me @Thanks

Comment: Try using the `class` attribute in place your `id` attribute (where you have `id='countryname_1'`) and change your `keyup` handler as `$(".td_class").on('keyup', '.clsCountryNo1', function(e) {.....`

Comment: ya i have tried .. it only working for single rows and not for dynamic rows.. it checking only the first rows and not for rest rows..

Comment: the code which i have tried in java script                        $(".td_class").on('keyup', '.country_no', function(e) {
    var icon1 = $('#countryname_1').val();
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (keyCode == 9 ) {
        if(icon1 == '' )
         {
       alert("Please Select an Item");
       document.form1.countryname_1.focus();
       }
       else{      
        $(".addmore").click();
        }
     }
   });